# How do I disable code folding in Spyder 4?

Tags: spyder

Spyder 4 is great.   Is there a way to disable code folding?  I find I am frequently collapsing sections of code when I try to set a break point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Preferences`

Click on Editor on the left, then on the display tab uncheck the "Show code folding" option. That should remove the small triangles from the left of main editor window.